# Multiple data array with the one set value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have a cakephp application that i want to save   posted to my base

[image]

I'm using  following code in  controller :

```
$ = $this->request->;
$['Link']['url'] = (',',$['Link']['url']);
$this->link->save($);
```

`var_dump`   :

`array(1) { ["Link"]=> array(2) { ["url"]=> array(2) { [0]=> (8) "first" [1]=> (5) "second" } ["linkset_id"]=> (1) "4" } }`

My table structure: **links table**    --> ID, url, linkset_id

But i get  following error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'`

How to save this  to  base ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because

```
$this->link->save($);
```

has a field named array probably because there is an empty fieldname somewhere. I would look at

```
[0]=> (8) "first"
```

There is no name for this array like

```
["Link"]=> array(2)
```

So the database is looking for a fieldname of Array which is not in your db table. Thus, the error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
```

To verify, i'd add a column named Array in your table and see what happens.